# How to re-add deleted articles using the same node ids?

Tags: database

I am running a drupal 7 website with about 1800+ articles. There were about 40 articles deleted overtime from the website. What I want to do is add  those articles again using the same deleted NIDs. How should I go about it?

Is adding these articles manually through phpMYAdmin a good idea? Are there other database tables I have to consider other than the following:

(1) node

(2) field_data_body

Comment: It depends what modules you have installed and how they’re configured, there could be a bunch more tables involved (there’s at least one more just for core) - a more robust approach would be to create the articles as new nodes then redirect requests for the old ones onto the new

Comment: I think a basic node does not create additional database records until we populate those fields (taxonomy, custom, module) with values before saving the node.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the amount of data you have at hand. If the missing nodes have simple structure with only default body field,title, none or just a few custom fields, then 40 is not that big number to sweat over the code, so I would do it via database UI as phpMyAdmin. Just note other involved tables like `node_revision` and custom field tables if nodes had ones.

However, if the missing nodes have multiple fields and too much data to enter manually, then I would create and upload data to 40 new nodes iterating:

```
$entity = entity_create('node', $values);
$service_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $entity);
$service_wrapper->title->set($product->title);
$service_wrapper->field_custom_field_1->set($data_1);
$service_wrapper->field_custom_field_2->set($data_2);
$service_wrapper->field_custom_field_N->set($data_N);
$service_wrapper->save();
```

Then I would replace nids either manually in `nodes` and `node_revision` tables or by saving the missing nids in form of `$nids = array(0 => 'first nid', 1 => 'second nid, 2 => '2nd nid', n => 'so forth')` and then iterating them through foreach loop in custom module's function.

Comment: My understanding is that once I add an article to 'node' and 'field_data_body' tables through phpMyAdmin, then I can edit it through Drupal admin section. Because a node does not create taxonomy terms and custom field contents until we save the node with those fields populated.

Comment: You are right 40 number is not big, I will go ahead and try adding an article through copy installation of drupal website and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Good news!

It worked with a few experiments. Once I run the following commands through SQL tab of phpMyAdmin for drupal database.

```
INSERT INTO `url_alias` (`source`, `alias`, `language`) VALUES ('node/470', '470', 'und');

INSERT INTO `node` (`nid`, `vid`, `type`, `language`, `title`, `uid`, `status`, `created`, `changed`, `comment`, `promote`, `sticky`, `tnid`, `translate`) VALUES (470, 470, 'article', 'und', 'Title of Old Article', 1, 0, 1452492094, 1520839370, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

INSERT INTO `node_revision` (`nid`, `vid`, `uid`, `title`, `log`, `timestamp`, `status`, `comment`, `promote`, `sticky`) VALUES (470, 470, 1, 'Title of Old Article', '', 1520839370, 0, 1, 1, 0);

INSERT INTO `field_data_body` (`entity_type`, `bundle`, `deleted`, `entity_id`, `revision_id`, `language`, `delta`, `body_value`, `body_summary`, `body_format`) VALUES ('node', 'article', 0, 470, 470, 'und', 0, 'Body of old article.', '', 'full_html');

INSERT INTO `field_revision_body` (`entity_type`, `bundle`, `deleted`, `entity_id`, `revision_id`, `language`, `delta`, `body_value`, `body_summary`, `body_format`) VALUES ('node', 'article', 0, 470, 470, 'und', 0, 'Body of old article.', '', 'full_html');
```

Then I can edit this article from drupal admin section like:

http://mywebsite.com/node/470/edit

And then I can add data to all the fields including taxonomy terms and custom fields.

It is working good so far, if something goes wrong I will update here.

So there are 5 basic tables for adding an article to drupal 7:

- url_alias
- node
- node_revision
- field_data_body
- field_revision_body